# printing one value from xml file by jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml file call products

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductsRoot>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>18</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chang</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>24 - 12 oz bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>19</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>3</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Aniseed Syrup</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 - 550 ml bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Products>         
 </ProductsRoot>
```

now I know how to print the list of all unitprice, but here I want to just print the uniprice of chang(productID 2), how can I do that?

```
$(products).find("Products").each(function() {
                    var unitprice = $(this).find("UnitPrice").text();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Isn't a conventional loop that checks if ProductName == "Chang" in each iteration a valid option?

Comment: actually, I created a list of all product and I am adding a click function for each product, I want a solution for every product...

Comment: _"adding a click function for each product"_ - when you click on what? This is xml, it has no concept of clickable things.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.filter`:

```
var price = $(products)
    .find("Products")
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).find("ProductName").text() == 'Chang';
    })
    .find("UnitPrice").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just a function like this one:

```
findUnitPrice = function(productName){
$(xmlDoc).find('Products').each(function(i,j)
{    
    if($(j).find('ProductName').html() == productName)
    {
        alert($(j).find('UnitPrice').html());
        return false;
    }
});
}
findUnitPrice('Chang');
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fn49w7ek/